# Extract City and State from a Full Address String following Specific Format

Tags: php, strpos

I have a set of addresses stored as individual strings. Here are possible values of those strings:

```
"Staples Center, 555 Test Drive, Los Angeles, CA 98112"
"555 Test Drive, Los Angeles, CA 98112"
"Los Angeles, CA"
"Los Angeles, CA 98112"
"Los Angeles"
```

The dates will always follow this format, where it could contain a venue name, street address, city, state, and zip

I would like to dynamically extract the city and state only from these strings:

```
$addresses_array = array(
    "Staples Center, 555 Test Drive, Los Angeles, CA 98112",
    "555 Test Drive, Los Angeles, CA 98112",
    "Los Angeles, CA",
    "Los Angeles, CA 98112",
    "Los Angeles"
);

foreach ($addresses_array as $address) {
    if (strpos($address, ',') !== false) {
        // extract the city and state
    }
}
```

Given the pattern of the address values, is there something I can do to extract the city and state based on the commas?

What I can see is that the city will always be the last comma in the string..

Comment: What happens in the last item in the array? How will you get the state there?

Comment: Can you share the expected output of the array?

Comment: Is the state always abbreviated and trailing the city with a comma? Maybe `([^,]+), ([A-Z]{2})` with `preg_match`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read it correct then you want the two last items (if available).
Use explode and then implode back the last two items.

```
$addresses_array = array(
    "Staples Center, 555 Test Drive, Los Angeles, CA 98112",
    "555 Test Drive, Los Angeles, CA 98112",
    "Los Angeles, CA",
    "Los Angeles, CA 98112",
    "Los Angeles"
);

foreach ($addresses_array as &$address) {
    $arr = explode(", ", $address);
    $address = implode(", ", array_slice($arr, -2));
}

var_dump($addresses_array);
```

Output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(21) "Los Angeles, CA 98112"
  [1]=>
  string(21) "Los Angeles, CA 98112"
  [2]=>
  string(15) "Los Angeles, CA"
  [3]=>
  string(21) "Los Angeles, CA 98112"
  [4]=>
  &string(11) "Los Angeles"
}
```

https://3v4l.org/Gqcid

If you don't want the zip, then you can explode the last item on space if $arr count is more than one.

```
foreach ($addresses_array as &$address) {
    $arr = explode(", ", $address);
    if(count($arr) >1){
        $arr[count($arr)-1] = explode(" ", $arr[count($arr)-1])[0];
        $address = implode(", ", array_slice($arr, -2));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "Los Angeles, CA"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "Los Angeles, CA"
  [2]=>
  string(15) "Los Angeles, CA"
  [3]=>
  string(15) "Los Angeles, CA"
  [4]=>
  &string(11) "Los Angeles"
}
```

https://3v4l.org/uKvke

Answer (score -1):

you can use `explode` and `count` function together

```php
$addresses_array = array(
    "Staples Center, 555 Test Drive, Los Angeles, CA 98112",
    "555 Test Drive, Los Angeles, CA 98112",
    "Los Angeles, CA",
    "Los Angeles, CA 98112",
    "Los Angeles"
);


foreach ($addresses_array as $address) {
    $addr = explode(",",$address);
    switch (count($addr))
    {
        case 1:
        case 2:
            echo  $addr[0];
            break;
        case 3:
            echo  $addr[1];
            break;
        case 4:
            echo  $addr[2];
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: i do not want to tell him all details! he should learn more not easy access to answers! @Bernhard